# Fitting a multivariate AR(1) with covariates?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, autoregressive, vector-autoregression

I have time series data where my main question of interest is making inference on predictive covariates, and accounting for the correlation (one observation each day) is just a nuisance issue. The model I would like to fit is: 
$$
y_t = X_t\beta + \Psi\epsilon_{t-1}+\omega_t
$$
where $y_t$ is a 1x3 vector of responses, $\omega_t$ is a 1x3 normal error term with diagonal covariance matrix (uncorrelated errors), and $\epsilon_{t-1}= \Psi \epsilon_{t-2}+\omega_{t-1}$.

Every package I can find on R either doesn't handle the covariates at all, or replaces $\Psi\epsilon_{t-1}$ with $\Psi y_{t-1}$. This is what the `vars` package for vector autoregression does and leads to incorrect inference on my coefficients. I am looking for one of three things:

1. Why fitting $\Psi y_{t-1}$ makes more sense than what I am trying to do.
2. A package that will fit the model as specified.
3. Advice on how to get the MLEs manually using `optim` or similar functions.

Comment: I am trying to understand what this model is. It does not look like multivariate AR (which is literally VAR) with covariates. Looks more like a multivariate regression with VARMA errors, but not in a standard representation.

Comment: I would be open to seeing your standard representations. In my ideal world, I would just be doing a multivariate regression. However because my observations are 1 per day over a series of months, they exhibit autocorrelation. Digging into the R package for vars, VAR() in R is just fitting three separate linear models after attaching the lag 1 times as predictors, which is not what I want.

Comment: Have you looked at the MARSS package in R?  It might give you enough flexibility to do what you want. The user manual for this package is available at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MARSS/vignettes/UserGuide.pdf.

Comment: What I think of a standard representation is something like $$y_t=\varphi_1 y_{t-1}+\beta x_t+\varepsilon_t+\theta_1\varepsilon_{t-1}$$ for ARMA(1,1) with external regressors; or $$y_t=\beta x_t+u_t,$$ $$u_t=\varphi_1 u_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t+\theta_1\varepsilon_{t-1}$$ for regression with ARMA(1,1) errors. These are the univariate cases, but after changing scalars to vectors and vectors to matrices, exactly the same representation works for the multivariate case.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Thanks for the heads up. Page 162 seems to lay out the scenario I'm looking at, with a tweak or two. So far I have not been able to get the right parameter estimates for my simulated dataset, but I am hopeful that I can get it worked out.

Comment: Good luck, @jntrcs! 

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let's do it for a univariate model. By induction you can note that $\psi\epsilon_{t-1}+\omega_t=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\psi^i\omega_{t-i}$. If $|\psi|<1$ this is equal to $1/(1-\psi L)\omega_t$ where $L$ is the lag operator. Thus, what you get is
$$
y_t=X_t\beta+\frac{1}{1-\psi L}\omega_t\\
(1-\psi L)y_t=(1-\psi L) X_t\beta+\omega_t\\
\Rightarrow y_t = X_t\beta+\psi(y_{t-1}-X_{t-1}\beta)+\omega_t.
$$

For the multivariate case, you will have a similar expression (but with matrices). Note that this is a non-linear estimation problem.

Comment: Thanks, but strategies for estimation in the multivariate case is what I am looking for.